# Are questions about the Tile tracker on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I want to ask a question about [Tile](https://www.thetileapp.com/), a Bluetooth location tracking device.

> Tile uses Bluetooth to communicate with the companion app on your smart phone or tablet. The Tile app "discovers" a Tile and establishes a connection to it using the Bluetooth signal. Once a Bluetooth connection is made between your Tile and mobile device, Tile then uses the location services of your mobile device to communicate up-to-date location information to the app.
>   <sub>-[How does Tile work?](https://support.thetileapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/201161926-How-does-Tile-work-)</sub>

Would questions about the Tile location tracker be on-topic?

Comment: So long as you're asking about an Internet of Things usage of the Tile and not about how to use it as a missile (or whatever), you should be fine!

Answer (score 4):

Sounds on-topic to me. Generally speaking, questions about using a device to sense and control remotely are on-topic, and we have [product tags](https://iot.stackexchange.com/tags) for many popular IoT devices for specific questions about their operation.

As stated in our [help center](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about...
>
> - controlling, automating and sensing the environment using electronics ('smart devices')
>
> ... you're in the right place!

I'd suggest you go ahead and ask your question — I'm pretty certain it will be received well here, but there's no substitute for actually asking a question and testing the waters. If you do want to check on meta first, consider editing with a draft of your question and let me know.

---

A question [has now been posted on the main site](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-can-i-pair-the-tile-to-the-phone) about the Tile tracker, which seems relatively well-received so far. See the [tile](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tile) tag for more information.